# printing list as table

Tags: python, list

I'm still new to python and trying out to print a list as a table.

```
headings = ["Bill Subgroup", "Sub Total", "Percentage"]
bs = ['Generation','Transmission','System Loss','Distribution','Subsidies',
      'Government Taxes', 'Universal Charges', 'Fit-All(Renewable)', 'Other Charges']
st = [1534.60, 220.84, 102.01, 758.94, 29.82, 309.72, 67.02, 33.13, 0]
per = ['50.21%','7.23%','3.34%','24.83%','0.98%','10.13%','2.19%','1.08%','0%']

print(headings)
for row in zip(headings,bs,st,per):
    print(row)
```

but the results is like this

```
['Bill Subgroup', 'Sub Total', 'Percentage']
('Bill Subgroup', 'Generation', 1534.6, '50.21%')
('Sub Total', 'Transmission', 220.84, '7.23%')
('Percentage', 'System Loss', 102.01, '3.34%')
>>>
```

which is not what I wanted and now it makes me confused and stuck which part is wrong

and no I don't kinda want to use the tabulate or the pandas I'm very sorry

helps are appreciated

Comment: Can you include what output you want? Your approach is correct, all you need is formatting rather than directly printing the tuple.

Comment: @rs_ You are telling what you don't want. But please also show us the template of how you want the output to be?

Comment: First of all you don't want to "zip" the "headings" with the other things.

Answer (score 0):

You could first obtain the appropriate column widths by finding the max of the length of each columns header and the length of its longest value.

Subsequently, you would then just need to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) essentially like you currently are along with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from typing import Union

COL_SEPERATOR = ' '

def main() -> None:
    headings = ["Bill Subgroup", "Sub Total", "Percentage"]
    bs = ['Generation','Transmission','System Loss','Distribution','Subsidies',
        'Government Taxes', 'Universal Charges', 'Fit-All(Renewable)', 'Other Charges']
    st = [1534.60, 220.84, 102.01, 758.94, 29.82, 309.72, 67.02, 33.13, 0]
    per = ['50.21%','7.23%','3.34%','24.83%','0.98%','10.13%','2.19%','1.08%','0%']
    cols = [bs, st, per]
    col_widths = [get_col_width(h, c) for h, c in zip(headings, cols)]
    print(
        COL_SEPERATOR.join(
            pad_val_to_col_width(h, w) for h, w in zip(headings, col_widths)
        )
    )
    for row in zip(*cols):
        print(
            COL_SEPERATOR.join(
                pad_val_to_col_width(v, w) for v, w in zip(row, col_widths)
            )
        )

def pad_val_to_col_width(val: Union[str, float], col_width: int) -> str:
    return f'{val:<{col_width}}'

def get_col_width(col_header: str, col_vals: list[Union[str, float]]) -> int:
    max_val_length = max(len(str(x)) for x in col_vals)
    return max(len(col_header), max_val_length)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Bill Subgroup      Sub Total Percentage
Generation         1534.6    50.21%    
Transmission       220.84    7.23%
System Loss        102.01    3.34%
Distribution       758.94    24.83%
Subsidies          29.82     0.98%
Government Taxes   309.72    10.13%
Universal Charges  67.02     2.19%
Fit-All(Renewable) 33.13     1.08%
Other Charges      0         0%
```